# If Q is a matrix of orthonormal bases, is Q times its transpose anything special?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that if Q is a matrix of orthonormal bases then Q transpose times Q is the identity matrix. Is Q times Q transpose anything special?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is also the identity matrix. This holds in general: if $B$ is a left inverse of a square matrix $A$, i.e. $BA=I$, then $B$ is also a right-inverse of $A$, i.e. $AB=I$.

Comment: So we get an interesting consequence.  If the rows of a real square matrix are orthonormal, then so are the columns.

Comment: Thanks, that was informative.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as Bananach indicates, you get the identity matrix again.  Here's another way to think of it, since the justification that inverses commute is not intuitively satisfying.

For a matrix $X$ with columns $x_1,\dots,x_k$, we have
$$
XX^T = \sum_{j=1}^l x_j x_j^T
$$
when the $x_i$ are orthonormal, $XX^T$ gives us the orthogonal projection onto the span of the vectors (note that $x_jx_j^T(v) = x_j \langle x_j,v\rangle$).

When the $x_i$ are orthonormal *and* span the space (that is, when $X^TX = I$), $XX^T$ is the orthogonal projection onto the entire space, which is simply the identity transformation.  That is, $XX^T = I$.