# Prove $AA^\top(v_a+v_b) = v_a$ when $A$ is orthonormal basis for $v_a$ orthogonal to $v_b$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Let $S$ be a vector space with mutually orthogonal subspaces $S_A, S_B$, with orthonormal bases ${a_1, a_2,...,a_m}$ and ${b_1, b_2,...,b_n}$.  Let $v_a \in S_A, v_b \in S_B$. Let matrix  $A = \begin{bmatrix}a_1 & a_2 & ... & a_m\end{bmatrix}$.

Prove $AA^\top(v_a+v_b) = v_a$.

### Proof

$AA^\top v_b = {\vec 0}$, since $v_b$ is orthogonal to every row in $A^\top$.

Since $v_a \in S_A$, there exist $c_1, c_2, ... c_m$ such that $v_a = c_1a_1 + c_2a_2 + ... c_ma_m$.

$A^\top v_a = \begin{bmatrix}c_1 \\ c_2 \\ ... \\ c_m\end{bmatrix}$, since $[A^\top v_a]_i = a_iv_a = a_i(c_i a_i) = a_i.$

$A \begin{bmatrix}c_1 \\ c_2 \\ ... \\ c_m\end{bmatrix} = c_1a_1 + c_2a_2 + ... + c_ma_m = v_a.$

QED.

### Questions

I appreciate any and all suggestions on both the proof and its writing.

1. Is the proof correct?
2. Is there a better approach? Or a better way of writing it? For example, I had to break the vectors and matrices up into their elements; is there a more elegant way that supersedes this?
3. What does this imply about $AA^\top$ in general? It seems that $AA^\top$ acts as like the identity on vectors that come from $A$'s colspace, and the zero matrix on vectors that are orthogonal to it.  Can this be generalized?
4. What does this imply about transpose resembling inverse in some ways, (in that $AA^T$ acts as the identity on these vectors)?  Can that be made more precise?

More generally speaking: The above shows that if all rows of $B$ have norm $1$, $Bx$ projects $x$ onto $B$'s rowspace, and $B^\top$ projects it back onto the full vector space; hence $B^\top B$ is identity for anything in $B$'s rowspace and zero for anything orthogonal to it.  The transpose is "inverting" the projection to the extent possible with the remaining information; but of course it is not a full inverse, since some information of $x$ is lost in the projection.  What does that tell us about transpose in general, for matrices that do not have norm $1$ for all rows?

Comment: Hi: you can use the fact that $A$ is an orthonomal basis to infer that $A \times \A^{T}$ = $ the identity matrix.That should simplify the proof..

Comment: @markleeds I believe $AA^\top$ is **not** the identity matrix; viz $AA^\top v_b = 0$.

Comment: good point. I must be wrong.  I concluded that in my head ( by multiplying each column by the other columns and using the fact that they are are orthonormal )  but I must be thinking about in the wrong way. My apologies. Hopefully someone can something more useful. My comment was de-useful !!!!!!

Comment: Hi SRobertJames: I found this thread but the matrix is square. I think $A$ is square also, right ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171256/if-q-is-a-matrix-of-orthonormal-bases-is-q-times-its-transpose-anything-special

Comment: @mark leeds No, $ \ A\ $ is an $\ (n+m)\times m\ $ matrix in this case, and $\ n\ $ can't be zero because a zero-dimensional space can't have an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @Ionza leggeria: The way I read it, $A$ is $m \times m$ ( it's a basis so column rank should equal row rank ).  If you can explain where you are getting $(n +m) \times m$, I'm willing to listen. Thanks.

Comment: What you have proven is the fact that: If W is a subspace of V and the columns of matrix A are the orthonormal vectors of W, then $AA^t$ is the projector on the subspace W